# BeautifulSoup does not scrape all data

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

I am trying to scrape a website but when I run this code it prints only half the data (including critics data). Here is my script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

inputfile = "Chicago.csv"
f = open(inputfile, "w")
Headers = "Name, Link\n"
f.write(Headers)

url = "https://www.chicagoreader.com/chicago/best-of-chicago-2011-food-drink/BestOf?oid=4106228"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

page_details = soup.find("dl", {"class":"boccat"})
Readers = page_details.find_all("a")

for i in Readers:
    poll = i.contents[0]
    link = i['href']
    print(poll)
    print(link)
    f.write("{}".format(poll) + ",https://www.chicagoreader.com{}".format(link)+ "\n")
f.close()
```

1. Is my scripting style wrong?
2. How to make codes short?
3. When to use `find_all` and `find` to not get attribute error. I read documentation but didn't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your code shorter, you can switch to Requests library. It's easy to use and precise. If you want to make it even shorter, you can use cssselect.

`find` selects the container and `find_all` selects individual item of that container in a for loop. Here is the completed code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv ; import requests

outfile = open("chicagoreader.csv","w",newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Name","Link"])

base = "https://www.chicagoreader.com"

response = requests.get("https://www.chicagoreader.com/chicago/best-of-chicago-2011-food-drink/BestOf?oid=4106228")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
for item in soup.select(".boccat dd a"):
    writer.writerow([item.text,base + item.get('href')])
    print(item.text,base + item.get('href'))
```

Or with find and find_all:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

base = "https://www.chicagoreader.com"

response = requests.get("https://www.chicagoreader.com/chicago/best-of-chicago-2011-food-drink/BestOf?oid=4106228")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
for items in soup.find("dl",{"class":"boccat"}).find_all("dd"):
    item = items.find_all("a")[0]
    print(item.text, base + item.get("href"))
```